# How to match table data to checkbox text in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to match each span text inside a table to text just next to each checkbox and then checkbox should be checked according to condition within if statement.

```
$('#sometable').find('span').each(function ()
 {
    var EmpDes = $(this).text();
    $('.divclass').find('.checkboxclass').each(function ()
      {
         var chktext = $(this).next().text();
         if (EmpDes == chktext)
         {
         $(this).prop('checked', true);
         }       
      });
  });
```

Comment: Try to make a fiddle to reproduce your error

Comment: oops... it's just a typo

Comment: @Johny Can u please explain how could i do that??

Comment: @oGeez it's just a typo here not in actual code

Comment: Please add a sample of your HTML. It would be even better if you created a runnable example on http://jsbin.com

Comment: Please clarify your question and add an HTML snippet of your table. Since you're a new member, I can tell you it helps a lot to answer your question. So if you like to have fast and good answers, improve your question, please.. :-)

Comment: Also mention what isn't working.